# React Material UI Override vertical alignment of Menu

Tags: css, material-ui

[The documentation of Material UI states](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-menu/#menu-positioning)

> When close to a screen edge, a basic menu vertically realigns to make sure that all menu items are completely visible.

This behavior is very inconvenient for the responsive pages I am writing since menus with a lot of items will start to pop over the menu button despite it being anchored to its bottom.

A fixed margin/distance isn't a solution because the position of the menu button might change vertically on a smaller screen.

How does one override or 'turn off' this kind of behavior?

Unfortunately, I can't share my code online but the [sandbox](https://pi62c1.csb.app/) of the Mui Documentation can be modified pretty easily to illustrate my point.

Below are two screenshots of the behavior I'm talking about.

[image: Screen with large height]

And on a smaller screen, this will happen.

[image: Sceen with small height]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the anchor position to show the menu to the right. This way the button will be always visible. Add this to the `Menu` props.

```
    anchorOrigin={{
      vertical: 'bottom',
      horizontal: 'right',
    }}
    transformOrigin={{
      vertical: 'top',
      horizontal: 'left',
    }}
```

[image]

You can expertiment the positions from [here](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-popover/#anchor-playground)

Another option is to set `min-height` based on the screen resolution using the `sx` prop.

```
sx={{maxHeight: {xs:250, md:500}}}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your solution! Moving the anchor is definitely a possible solution but it changes the design. However the second option where you set the maxHeight for different screen sizes solves my problem!

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if setting `max-height` on the `Menu` would work for you? It's a less hacky solution. You could even use `calc`

```
sx= {{ maxHeight: 100 }}
sx= {{ maxHeight: "calc(100% - 40px)" }}
```

OR

```
PaperProps= {{ sx: { maxHeight: 100 } }}
PaperProps= {{ sx: { maxHeight: "calc(100% - 40px)" } }}
```

Comment: `max-height` right?

Comment: Hi thank you for your suggestion, however this one doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: @Melon_The_Great is working but not solving your problem, or you can't get it to work? FYI: I was looking into the source code and how to disable it, but I might look again. The `Menu` is based on the `Popover` it seems like

Comment: Clarification: It doesn't solve the problem _in my code_. I have several menu buttons with varying length of menuItems. A fixed height just looks very ugly for this and the calculated height produces very unpredictable results (sometimes covering the button, sometimes covering half, etc.)